# Does ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads get the value based on processModel tag in machine.config?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0, threadpool

I have set the maxIoThreads and maxWorkerThreads in machine.config to 100.

```
<processModel autoConfig="false" maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100"/>
```

However when i am debugging the ASP.net 4.0  webapplication code in Visual Studio I am seeing that ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads returns the count as 200 for both of them.

```
        int workerThreads;
        int portThreads;
        System.Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out portThreads);
        //workerThreads & portThreads both get the value of 200
```

My question is there any relation between processmodel tag in machine.config and ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads?

Answer (score 1):

Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1.aspx

> maxWorkerThreads = Configures the maximum number of worker threads to use for the process on a per-CPU basis. For example, if this value is 25 on a single-processor server, ASP.NET uses the runtime APIs to set the process limit to 25. On a two-processor server, the limit is set to 50.

Moreover make sure you have defined the minFreeThread in httpruntime according to this guideline

> The value of this attribute must be equal to or greater than the minFreeThread attribute setting in the httpRuntime configuration section.